# Change text in div when bootstrap slider picture is active

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, class, slideshow

I'm using a bootstrap slider, and for every picture on the slide, the text in a `div` underneath the slide is going to change with different information.

I've been trying to target bootstrap's active slider like this;

```
$('#myCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function(){
  var id = ev.relatedTarget.id;
  switch (id) {
    case "easy":
      document.getElementById('#container1');
      $('#container1').show();
      break;

    case "3":
      break;

    case "3":
      break;

    default:

  }
});
```

Without any luck. If it's needed for clarification purposes, here's my html for the bootstrap slider.

```
<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<center>
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
  <div id="easy" class="item active">
    <img src="skeleton.png" alt="Chania">
  </div>

  <div id="medium" class="item">
    <img src="creeper.png" alt="Chania">

  </div>

  <div id="hard" class="item">
    <img src="enderman.png" height="200" width="200" alt="Flower">
  </div>

  <div id="extreme" class="item">
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <img class="slime animated infinite bounce" src="slime.png" height="200" width="200" alt="Flower">
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Left and right controls -->
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
```

So how should i go about this?

Comment: Can you please provide a jsFiddle / codepen?

Comment: `document.getElementById('#container1');` is redundant - 1. you don't assign to it a variable, so it does nothing, and 2. the # doesn't work with this method - it's used in the jQuery/CSS selector syntax. Your next line using jQuery to show the element is correct and sufficient, you don't need this other line as well.

Comment: Also, where is "container" in your sample? It doesn't exist. You can automatically assign captions to images in a bootstrap carousel as per this example: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp